# .then() is undefined in React-Native

Tags: typescript, redux

I'm using Typescript, React, and Redux. I fail to understand why the function **.then()** isn't working on my *Promise* function. All this code works perfectly fine in a simple **React** (NOT Native) application.

Interface:

```
export interface IAuthenticationSigninAction extends AnyAction {
    error?: boolean;
    payload: {
        userEmail: string;
        userPassword: string;
        isAuthenticated?: boolean;
    };
}
```

Function in reducer (NOT reducer function. That is fine):

```
export function authenticationSignin(email: string, password: string): 
IAuthenticationSigninAction {
    return {
        type: AUTHENTICATION_SIGNIN_RESPONSE,
        payload: {
            userEmail: email,
            userPassword: password
        }
    }
}
```

Dispatches in Container:

```
export interface IDispatchProps {
        authenticationSignin: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<IAuthenticationSignin>;
    }
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: any) {
    return {
        authenticationSignin: (email: string, password: string): Promise<IAuthenticationSignin> => dispatch(authenticationSignin(email, password))
    };
}
```

Lastly, the code that crashes because of the **.then()**:

```
handleSignIn() {
        this.props.authenticationSignin(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.isAuthenticated);
        });
    }
```

The error:
**

> undefined is not a function (evaluating
>   'this.props.authenticationSignin(this.state.email,
>   this.state.password).then(function (response) {
>       console.log(response.isAuthenticated); })')

**

[As per my function signature, I compare to **fetch** which is undoubtedly a promise and they're identical minus the obvious changes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puQU3.png)

Anyone got some advice on how to deal with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this is working correctly in another React app?  you can only do `this.props.someActionCreator().then()` if `someActionCreator` is a thunk that returns a promise.  Your `authenticationSignin` function is not a thunk, and not returning a promise.

Comment: @markerikson Hey, Mark. Yeah it does work perfectly fine in a React Web app. There is a typo in the function authenticationSignin. Should be *authenticationSignin: (email, password): Promise<IAuthenticationSigninAction>;* . Interestingly enough, if I put a console.log statement in the reducer function, it will print perfectly fine. It's just the **.then()** blows it up.

Comment: Well, as I said, based on the code you're showing right now, it should not be working, period.  You're not using a thunk, and you're not returning a promise.  So yes, I would expect the original action to be dispatched, but the `.then()` part is trying to call a function on a non-existent return value.

Comment: @markerikson I assure you it is a thunk and works perfectly fine in a web application as I literally copied and pasted the necessary pieces of code. Perhaps I'm not understanding then, please give me an example of how *you* would define a thunk function, if you don't mind.

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong about it being a thunk, but the example you're showing is definitely not returning a promise.  Is it possible your other app has a Redux middleware that's intercepting the dispatched action and returning a promise?

Comment: @markerikson totally agree. In fact, you might be right about that (I hope!). I might have forgotten to place middleware in one of my directories since I was sort of rushing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Per discussion in the comments, this is what a thunk action creator that returns a promise would look like:

```
export function someThunkReturningAPromise() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const promise = someAjaxLib.fetchSomeData();

        // could also do some dispatching in here, or anything else you want

        // this is the important part
        return promise;
    }
}

// later, in a component file:

import {someThunkReturningAPromise} from "./actions";

const actionCreators = {someThunkReturningAPromise};

class MyComponent extends Component {
    handleClick = () => {
        this.props.someThunkReturningAPromise()
           .then( () => {
               // this is only possible because the thunk action creator
               // returned a promise
           });
    }
}

export default connect(null, actionCreators)(MyComponent);
```